# How concatenate two char arrays to open file from fopen in C?

Tags: c, linux, file, char, kernel

I am facing problem in dynamically opening a file using "fopen" in c.
The following code is concatenating two arrays and it works fine it opens the file.

```
char path[50] = "/boot/config-";
char kernel[50] = "3.16.3";
strcat(path, kernel);
FILE *infile = fopen(path, "r"); //file opening successfully
if(infile == NULL){printf("failed to open file");}
```

But, when i try to fill kernel array dynamically and concatenate it with path array it fails to open a file.

```
char path[50] = "/boot/config-";
char kernel[50] = "";

FILE *fp = popen("uname -r", "r");//executing command for kernel version 3.16.3

if (fp != NULL){
    while (fgets(kernel, sizeof(kernel)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", kernel);//print 3.16.3
    }
    strcat(path,kernel);
}

FILE *infile = fopen(path, "r"); //failed to open file
if(infile == NULL){printf("failed to open file");}
```

Comment: Probably contain newline.

Comment: Do `printf("'%s'", kernel);` instead, and you'll see that BLUEPIXY is probably right

Comment: DoomProg hit it on the head - regardless of whether it is the cause of your problem here, assigning static strings to character arrays like this is wrong. You are effectively statically allocating an array, and then re-pointing the pointer to that array to another memory location containing the static `"/boot/config-"` or `"3.16.3"` or `""`. You need to use `strcpy` or the like to put a string into a `char` array.

Comment: Always check what exactly it contains. the easy way to do this is just `printf("|%s|", path)` then you instantly notice it!

Comment: BTW, you can use `fgets(kernel, sizeof(kernel), fp)`. `fgets` will read at most `sizeof(kernel)-1` characters, reserving one element of the array for the terminating null character.

Comment: @Politank-Z I don`t follow, according to this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/183842/initializing-char-array-with-string it is perfectly acceptable to what he is doing.

Comment: @Politank-Z: That is a perfectly acceptable way to initialize a character array in C.

Comment: when a open operations fails, the program needs to handle the error (and usually, if the error is not handlable, then exit.  Your program keeps right on executing, after printing the message about failing to open the file.  that needs to be corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets includes the newline. its hard to notice sometimes that`s why I generally use this print for singular test purpose, you can exactly see if you have odd characters new lines etc.

```
printf("|%s|", path)
```

easiest way to fix that is to just do:

```
unsigned int strlength = strlen(path);
if (path[strlength - 1] == '\n') {
    path[strlength - 1] = '\0';    
}
```

Comment: Technically, the return of `strlen` is `size_t` instead of `unsigned`. While they are essentially the same via a `#define`, it is good habit to match your type to the return type.

Answer (score 0):

My personal use of a dynamic fopen in a project.

```
#define LOG
#define LOG_FILE "s:/results"
#define MODE "_MODE_1"

#ifdef LOG
FILE* fp = fopen(LOG_FILE MODE ".txt", "w");
#endif
```

Comment: You could at least explain that you are counting on automatic concatenation  of string literals in C for this to work. Then you'd perhaps realize that the question asks how to concatenate non-literal string variables so this method   does not apply.